# What difference is there when sending a dictionary rather than a struct through Game Center?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, game-center, gamekit

I'm implementing a multiplayer mode for my iOS game using Game Center.

It is pretty much a turn-based RPG (but it uses the real-time model), so I don't really need to send data too often.

I've noticed that most examples send data using a struct. One property being the message kind, and the other properties just extra parameters to interpret the message.

I, personally, would enjoy sending a dictionary rather than a struct for no particular reason other than ease of work (in my specific case at least).

I want to know the objective differences between sending structs and dictionaries through Game Center, so I can measure whether it is actually worth doing one over the other.

Some factors:

- It's a turn-based RPG. You wait for your rival to send a message with their decision. There is little dynamism, so the data exchange is not quite frequent. If anything, I'd say that it will usually take like 5 seconds for a player to make a decision.
- All my data is sent in reliable mode.
- My dictionary will usually contain around 3-5 keys, where the values will usually be `NSString` or `NSNumber` instances.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries use a lot more space than a simple struct.
With dictionaries, you have a lot of flexibility -> You can create your dictionary at run time and send it, as long as all the objects in your dictionary are serialisable. The code is also very easy to write.
Sending a dictionary is a great option, if you need to do things like send arrays, or send multiple objects that you are not aware of at compile time. In fact, if you know that all the objects that you use in your messages are serialisable, then you need just one encode / decode method that could be used for all the dictionaries.

Example: [Convert nsdictionary to nsdata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7249297/convert-nsdictionary-to-nsdata)

Structs typically use less space.
You need to define your struct at compile time - you need to know the structure of your data that you plan to send. You can't do this dynamically.
If you need to send multiple arrays, you need to know the size before hand, since you can't send multiple variable length arrays at run time.

**For your situation, if it is "turn based", and if a couple of seconds here or there won't make too much of a difference, then an NSDictionary may be more convenient for you.**

If you were writing a first person shooter, or some kind of action game that needs to send data 30 or 60 times a second, then you would use the smallest format possible to send your data to avoid latency problems.

In an ideal world, regardless of whether it was turn based, or an fps, you wouldn't want to send more data than necessary, because you are wasting bandwidth, and your app will take longer to send / receive messages. The optimal method would be to create your own format where you minimise the number of wasted bits (example: if you know that a number you send will never be greater than 10, then you use only 4 bits to represent it). But in reality, it may making coding such an efficient encoding / decoding method tricky.