# In NSURLSession HTTPBody must be NSData?

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, afnetworking-3

When I use `AFNetworking` to post parameters is `NSMutableDictionary`, this request is succeeded.

But when I used `NSURLSession`, the self.request!.HTTPBody must be NSData, so request failed.

How can I use NSURLSession to make request succeeded?

```
postDict[@"jgId"] = "1000000000";
[manager GET:SELECTDEPART parameters:postDict success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
  NSLog(@"-----%@", error);
}];

//use  NSData

NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(postDict, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
let params = ["jgId": "1000000000"]
let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: [JSONSerialization.WritingOptions(rawValue: 0)])

var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://my-url.com")!, cachePolicy: .returnCacheDataElseLoad, timeoutInterval: 30)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.httpBody = data
request.allHTTPHeaderFields = [:]

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

}
```

Comment: You need to give answer in Objective C not in swift because OP is working with Obj C.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, for NSURLSession [you need NSData](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013509-SW15).

But you can easily [convert an NSDictionary to NSData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7249297/convert-nsdictionary-to-nsdata) by using NSKeyedArchiver.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `GET` method to request data from server, so your parameters is not sent by request HTTPBody data. Your params is simple past via request URL.

In question You have `SELECTDEPART` as base URL of request and `postDict` as parameter. The following code use NSURLSession to make `GET` request with `parameters`

```
// get request URL from base URL and params
NSURLComponents *components = [NSURLComponents componentsWithString:@"http://stackoverflow.com"]; // some thing like SELECTDEPART in your question
NSDictionary *params = @{ @"q": @"ios", @"count": @"10" };  // params of request like your postDict

NSMutableArray *queryItems = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString *key in params.allKeys) {
    [queryItems addObject:[NSURLQueryItem queryItemWithName:key value:params[key]]];
}
components.queryItems = queryItems;
NSURL *url = components.URL;
// create request
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
request.HTTPMethod = @"GET";

// data task with NSURLSession
NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (!error) {
        // parse your data here
    } else {
        // handle error here
    }
}];
[task resume];
```